# Combining 2 algorithms in grasshoper in order to get the area/ Sqft of the floor

Tags: architecture, grasshopper, rhino3d

I want to combine 2 algorithms in grasshopper so that I can get the area/sqft of the curve however I can't get the two curves to combine.
I made 2 twisted towers. One is going one way and the other I just reversed. it's 80 floors in total and the ellipses on the ground are what I want to combine so that I can get the combined area/sqft of those 2 curves on top of each other. (The number in the middle of the ellipses). I created 2 different algorithms the first 3 images are from my first algorithm posted here. The first image is to show the tower and the 2 overlapping ellipses that I want to combine the curves into. The second image is the algorithm I used in order to get to that point. The third image is to show basically what I want to happen but not just with the base floor but with all other floors above it.:[1st IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrCQZ.png)[2nd IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUImL.jpg)[3rd IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaI1w.jpg)[3rd IMG AlGO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLC8Z.png)
Here is the second algorithm I did but similar to the first one I couldn't figure out what was wrong with it.[2nd ALGO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPXhO.jpg)[2nd ALGO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMvAJ.jpg)

I tried using the Divide curve and region union but quickly got stuck in that part since i couldn't apply it to the rest of the floor above the base one and since both twisted towers start off with the same base I can't even be sure of whether or not I did it correctly.
The second algorithm is something my teacher actually helped me with but didn't have enough time to fully understand and fix the problem. So I tried fixing it later that day but quickly got stumped. I'm still fairly new to grasshopper so I can't be sure of what I did wrong and what I can do to fix it. Any help is appreciated.